# EWS: Find mail by EntryID/ItemID in sent items?

Tags: email, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I have the EntryID and ItemID of a mail, how can I using EWS get the mail not knowing if it's in the "Inbox" or "Sent items"?

I've tried this..

```
Dim ewsID As String = "AAAAAMgC9AZo0nACt4jVCOhhCmcHAF35p973GUpBjIUVAx1CYigAAAAAABEAAF35p973GUpBjIUVAx1CYigAAiwdaBwAAA=="
Dim email As EmailMessage = EmailMessage.Bind(service, New Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemId(ewsID))
```

But it doesn't find anything.

Help :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have HexEntryId from PR_EntryId or from Outlook OOM app you need to use convertItem to convert to an EWSid to use eg based on what you posted this should work

```
        String ItemId = "AAAAAMgC9AZo0nACt4jVCOhhCmcHAF35p973GUpBjIUVAx1CYigAAAAAABEAAF35p973GUpBjIUVAx1CYigAAiwdaBwAAA==";
        AlternateId HexId = new AlternateId(IdFormat.HexEntryId, BitConverter.ToString(Convert.FromBase64String(ItemId)).Replace("-", ""), "Mailbo@domain.com");
        AlternateIdBase Converted = service.ConvertId(HexId, IdFormat.EwsId);
        EmailMessage Message = EmailMessage.Bind(service, new ItemId(((AlternateId)Converted).UniqueId));
```

Cheers
Glen